# how to spawn enemy ships in swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am currently trying to create a space ship game that you shoot at the enemy that moves towards you from the top of the screen to the bottom of the screen and you also try to avoid the enemy from crashing into you. My enemy is not spawning.

This is my spawn enemy code:

```
func spawnEnemy(){

    let randomXStart = random(min:gameArea.minX, max: gameArea.maxX)
    let randomXEnd = random(min: gameArea.minX, max:gameArea.maxX)

    let spawnPoint = CGPoint(x: randomXStart, y: self.size.height * 1.2)
    let endPoint = CGPoint(x: randomXEnd, y: -self.size.height * 0.2)

    let enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "enemyShip")
    enemy.setScale(1)
    enemy.position = spawnPoint
    enemy.zPosition = 2
    self.addChild(enemy)

    let moveEnemy = SKAction.move(to: endPoint, duration: 1.5)
    let deleteEnemy = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let enemySequence = SKAction.sequence([moveEnemy, deleteEnemy])
    enemy.run(enemySequence)


    let dx = endPoint.x - spawnPoint.x
    let dy = endPoint.y - spawnPoint.y
    let amountToRotate = atan2(dy, dx)
    enemy.zRotation = amountToRotate

}
```

Comment: Where is the Y value of spawnPoint?

Comment: it is right here let spawnPoint = CGPoint(x: randomXStart, y: self.size.height * 1.2)

Comment: I know that.  Where is it on the screen?

Comment: it is on the top of the screen

Answer (score 0):

Your enemy is spawned, you can't see it because you didn't set the `size` value. The default one is `(width: 0, height: 0)`.

`enemy.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)`

Also, another way to check if the `enemy` object spawned is to look at the node count number to see if it increases after you call the `spawnEnemy` function.

For this you need to have the `view.showsNodeCount = true`.

Comment: I added the enemy size in my code but the enemy still does not appear

Comment: But if you set the enemy.position = CGPoint.zero you see it?

Comment: I still don't see it if I add enemy.position = CGPoint.zero